# Angular (4): pass a class object from child to parent component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I can pass a class object like `Person` into a `child` component from `parent` component without any problems. But I would like to also manipulate that object in `child` component and pass it back to `parent` component.

**This is the child component class:**

```
export class ActionPanelComponent {
  @Input('company') company: Company;
  @Output() notify: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {
  }

  public deleteCompany() {
    console.log('display company');
    console.log(this.company);
    // FIXME: Implement Delete
    this.company = new Company();
  }

  public onChange() {
    this.notify.emit(this.company);
  }

}
```

**This is the html of this component (excerpt):**

```
<div class="row" (change)="onChange()">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <button md-icon-button >
      <md-icon>skip_previous</md-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
```

**This is the parent component class (excerpt):**

```
  public onNotify(company: Company):void {
    this.company = company;
  }
```

**And the parent component html (excerpt):**

```
<action-panel [company]="company" (notify)="onNotify($event)"></action-panel>
```

I am doing something wrong because I cannot pass my `company` object inside the `.emit` and nothing works.

What is the correct way of achieving two way object binding between components?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by manipulate in the child? set an instance attribute? if so, then the changes will be reflected immediately in the parent, as you are passing the value by reference.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I pass a `company` object to the child. In the child I want to clear all the fields of this `company` object. It doesn't work :(

Comment: Just add the `Type` to `EventEmitter`: `new EventEmitter<Company>();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it like this to tell TS which `Type` the `EventEmitter` should `emit`:

```
export class ActionPanelComponent {
  @Input('company') company: Company;
  @Output() notify = new EventEmitter<Company>(); //<---- On this line!

  constructor() {
  }

  public deleteCompany() {
    console.log('display company');
    console.log(this.company);
    // FIXME: Implement Delete
    this.company = new Company();
  }

  public onChange() {
    this.notify.emit(this.company);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved one problem, but the `onChange()` method doesn't fire still.

Comment: @DenissM. Well, when does the `div` fire a `changed` `event`? I don't really see that happening.. Can you call the event on e.g. a button click instead?

Comment: True :D I moved ` this.notify.emit(this.company);` into the `deleteCompany()` method. Thanks now it works great!

Answer (score 5):

You were missing the type on the initialization of the [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter).

You could use the [Output](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) binding to implement the two way object binding:

**Child component (ts)**

```
export class ActionPanelComponent {
    @Input('company') company: Company;
    @Output() companyChange: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter<Company>();

    constructor() {
    }

    public deleteCompany() {
       console.log('display company');
       console.log(this.company);
       // FIXME: Implement Delete
       this.company = new Company();
    }

    public onChange() {
       this.companyChange.emit(this.company);
    }

}
```

**Parent component (html)**

```
<action-panel [(company)]="company"></action-panel>
```

So like this you don't need to declare an extra function `onNotify`. If you do need the `onNotify` function, use another name for the output binding:

```
export class ActionPanelComponent {
    @Input('company') company: Company;
    @Output() notify: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter<Company>();

    constructor() {
    }

    public deleteCompany() {
       console.log('display company');
       console.log(this.company);
       // FIXME: Implement Delete
       this.company = new Company();
    }

    public onChange() {
       this.notify.emit(this.company);
    }

}
```

Comment: This was very useful Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

It is a workaround that worked for me, if it is helpful for anyone.

Your parent parent-component.ts would be like;

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'parent',
templateUrl:'./parent.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class Parent implements OnInit {

let parentInstance= this; //passing instance of the component to a variable
constructor() { }

parentMethod(var:<classtyepyourchoice>){
console.log(var);
}



 ngOnInit() {
 }



}
```

In you parent.component.html, you would have your child

```
 <child [parent]="parentInstance" ></child>
```

This object will be available in the child component

Now, in your child component you will receive this like

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'child',
templateUrl:'./child.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class Child implements OnInit {

@Input('parent') parent;
constructor() { }

childMethod(yourClassObject){
this.parent.parentMethod(yourClassObject);
}



 ngOnInit() {
 }



}
```

Thus, you can pass classobject from your child, like this, it worked for me.